# Need to convert PHP Curl Request to JavaScript (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

Currently I am having Curl request in PHP like below,

```
$url = "http://localhost:8500/v1/catalog/service/api?passing&tag=%2Fu%2Fdeepak%2F211%2Flocalhost"
$ch = curl_init($url);

function _exec($ch) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info  = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if ($info['http_code'] !== 200) {
            if ($info['http_code'] === 404) {
                throw new Exception('Unable to find requested requested Consul API: ' . $info['url']);
            } else {
                $message = 'Url: ' . $info['url'];
                $error = curl_error($ch);
                if (! empty($response)) {
                    $message .= ' -- Response: ' . $response;
                }
                if (! empty($error)) {
                    $message .= ' -- Error: ' . $error;
                }
                throw new Exception('Failed to call Consul API: ' . $message);
            }
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($response);
}
```

Need to convert this same code into JavaScript and run it on Node.js. Mostly I found solutions using only using AJAX. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you just need an ajax. Try searching how to do an Ajax call in javascript.

Comment: Why can‘t you use ajax… I don‘t know any other method if I remember the definition right

Comment: @ShadowLp174  I would like to use node fetch or plain javascript xhr request.

Comment: XHR is not plain JavaScript, it is an extension provided by browsers. Node Fetch is an HTTP library for Node.JS. Are you using Node.js or a browser?

Comment: I provided an answer of node fetch below @Deepak

Comment: Ajax is a term meaning "Making an HTTP request from JavaScript embedded in a web page". cURL is a library for making HTTP requests. If you are running in a web browser then Ajax is the name for the thing you want to do.

Comment: I would agree with Quentin. '

Comment: @Quentin I am using node

Comment: Deepak then the answer I posted below will work for you.

Comment: Then you said you wanted to use node fetch. You should read its documentation and make an attempt to use it. If you get stuck, then ask a question here (showing your attempt). Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. Will try below solution and update. Thank you

Comment: But isn‘t an XHR request AJAX too? @Quentin

Comment: @ShadowLp174 — Yes. I never said otherwise.  I refer you to my comment starting "Ajax is a term meaning…"

Comment: Oh sorry… I pinged you and not Deepak

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScripts Fetch API (available in your browser) to make network requests.

If using node, you will need to install the node-fetch package.

```
const url = "http://localhost:8500/v1/catalog/service/api?passing&tag=%2Fu%2Fdeepak%2F211%2Flocalhost";
    
    const options = {
      headers: {
        //Authorization: "Bearer 6Q************"
      }
    };
    
    fetch(url, options)
      .then( res => res.json() )
      .then( data => console.log(data) );
```

Comment: Fetch is not natively in Node.js, which poster is asking for. Using axios would make it work both in Node.js and browser, just a tip.

Comment: @Anuga — Axios is not available natively in Node.js either … and the OP isn't asking how to run it in the browser.